# Browser only audio clipping

Tags: mac, google-chrome, audio, browser, html5

I have a strange sound clipping problem that seems to be isolated to browser/html5/flash audio. It seems to be isolated only to videos played through my browser and happens the same whether I use the HTML5 or Flash video version or online music sites like Spotify (Spotify desktop is fine). If I download the actual video and play in VLC/Quicktime there is no clipping (and strangely it plays even louder without a problem). It happens in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari. The only way to eliminate it is to lower the video applications' software volume control, so it is as if my browser html5/flash are somehow outputting volume at 105% capacity instead of 100%. My only theory is that HTML5 and Flash are going through some common 'browser audio' resource (since it is happening on all browsers) on my mac causing software clipping in my audio chain, but I cannot figure out what/where this is and how to fix it.

My audio preferences are set to use internal speakers and/or headphones. I'm not running any sound boosters like Boom2 (which even if I were would affect all Mac audio equally). What on earth is causing this?